# AJAX post via vb.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I need to do an AJAX post via my vb.net page. This post also attaches the xml file needed to validate the post and then submits it to the link. I dont get any errors when i do the post but the file doesnt get submitted also. I will add my code to this question, thanks in advance.

```
Public Shared XMLString As String

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    xmldoc.Load("d:/jobfeed.xml")
    XMLString = xmldoc.OuterXml
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", POSTtoEP)


End Sub



Public Shared Function POSTtoEP() As [String]
    Dim strurl As String = "https://www.executiveplacements.com/Job_Post_Xml.asp"
    Dim strType As String = "POST"
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("function POSTtoEP () {")
    sb.Append("$.ajax({")
    sb.Append("type:" & strType & ",")
    sb.Append("url:" & strurl & ",")
    sb.Append("data: { XmlPacket:" & XMLString & ",")
    sb.Append("contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    sb.Append("dataType: xml,")
    sb.Append("success: function(data){,")
    sb.Append("},")
    sb.Append("error:function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('Error processing data. Please try again.);")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("});")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

End Class

[image: This is the javascript output]

Comment: So what does the JavaScript code this outputs finally look like?

Comment: I have attached the output image to the question

Comment: That looks like it should cause several syntax errors ... for starters, it misses quotes around text literals in multiple places.

Comment: Exactly, if it gave me an error it would be better as i then could work from there to resolve it, however there's no output from the post. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Well the suggestion would be that you _fix_ those errors ...

Comment: The XML needs to be inside a string. When you run this in a browser, the browser's console must be spitting some errors I think. You can check the errors there and use the info to fix the script. P.S. what a horrible way to build script though, no wonder you get syntax errors because it's really hard to see what the finished code will be. There are better ways to inject your VB variables into it.

Comment: @ADyson, can you provide me with another way to build this script/inject VB variables ? i have edited my code plenty times with no solution.

Comment: You could write the script in your aspx page like a normal script, and then inject the VB variables using <% %> tags. Or use XSLT or another transformation language to generate a string or even a separate .JS file. There are probably other ways too, but those are the obvious ones that spring to mind. Both will be easier to maintain than using a stringbuilder.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try that and revert back

Answer (score 0):

There were quotation marks and braces missing in that code. Also the script was declaring a function that was never called.

```
Public Shared Function POSTtoEP() As [String]
    Dim strurl As String = "https://www.executiveplacements.com/Job_Post_Xml.asp"
    Dim strType As String = "POST"
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.AppendLine("function POSTtoEP () {")
    sb.AppendLine("$.ajax({")
    sb.AppendLine("type:""" & strType & """,")
    sb.AppendLine("url:""" & strurl & """,")
    sb.AppendLine("data: { XmlPacket:""" & XMLString & """},")
    sb.AppendLine("contentType:""application/x-www-form-urlencoded"",")
    sb.AppendLine("dataType: ""xml"",")
    sb.AppendLine("success: function(data){ ")
    sb.AppendLine("alert(data);")
    sb.AppendLine("},")
    sb.AppendLine("error: function(error, message){")
    sb.AppendLine("alert('Error processing data. Please try again.');")
    sb.AppendLine("}")
    sb.AppendLine("});")
    sb.AppendLine("};")
    sb.AppendLine("POSTtoEP();")
    sb.AppendLine("</script>")
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

This code renders correct javascript. However if Job_Post_Xml.asp doesn't return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then ContentType needs to be amended. Otherwise it will produce parse errors. I believe Job_Post_Xml.asp has gzip encoding but can't test it here because it's a cross domain request.